Mixing Network Acl's and publicNetworkAccess with storage account bicep module?
So I have a bicep module for storage account that is quite simple tbh:
resource storage_account 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' = {
  sku: {
    name: sku
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  name: name
  location: location
  tags: tags
  identity: identity
  properties: {
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    isHnsEnabled: is_hns_enabled == false ? null : is_hns_enabled
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      virtualNetworkRules: vnet_rules
      defaultAction: network_acls_default_action
    }
    allowSharedKeyAccess: allow_shared_key_access
    accessTier: 'Hot'
  }
}


So this set Storage account with Public Network Access set to: Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses and later, some Private Endpoints are added to the mix.
The thing is, now I need to create just one storage account with Public Network Access set to: Enabled for all networks as I need to store linked templates there and per Micrososft, this is the only way to get them from storage account (so not firewall settings etc).
The problem is, if I set publicNetworkAccess: Enabled, all ACL's and private endpoints does not make to much sense but what is I think bigger problem, is I can't set publicNetworkAccess: to Disabled as this will also brick all network Acls for that storage and only private endpoints will be working, right?
I thought that if I set publicNetworkAccess to "Null" I can still use ACL but it looks like this is not possible, as only correct values are Enabled or Disabled...
resource storage_account 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' = {
  sku: {
    name: sku
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  name: name
  location: location
  tags: tags
  identity: identity
  properties: {
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    isHnsEnabled: is_hns_enabled == false ? null : is_hns_enabled
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowSharedKeyAccess: allow_shared_key_access
    accessTier: 'Hot'
    publicNetworkAccess: enablePublicNetworkAccess ? 'Enabled' : 'Null'

    networkAcls: enablePublicNetworkAccess ? null : {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      virtualNetworkRules: vnet_rules
      defaultAction: network_acls_default_action
    }
  }
}

Of course, simples workaround here would be to either use different module or just create resource and not use the module for this single storage account.
Any idea if this is possible to achieve?

You can keep publicNetworkAccess to 'Enabled' and conditionally configure networkAcls based on enablePublicNetworkAccess. @filipdrzewiecki refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal

but this does not make to much sense me. How does publicNetworkAccess: Enabled plays with NetworkAcls?
I've checked arm code for existing storage accounts with networkAcl and generated arm returns publicNetworkAccess: Enabled


Mixing Network Acl's and publicNetworkAccess with storage account bicep module

Yes, your understanding is correct. As per the bicep documentation for storage account it doesn't support for explicit value null in its private network access as it only possible to Pick one among the two option which was available.
Bicep:
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' = {
  name: 'myvksbstoragevk'
  location: 'eastus'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  tags: {
    environment: 'test'
    project: 'bicep-sample'
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'None'
  }
  properties: {
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    isHnsEnabled: true
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      virtualNetworkRules: [] 
      defaultAction: 'Allow'  
    }
    allowSharedKeyAccess: true
    accessTier: 'Hot'
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled' // Set to 'Enabled' or 'Disabled' as needed
  }
}

output storageAccountId string = storageAccount.id
output storageAccountPrimaryEndpoints object = storageAccount.properties.primaryEndpoints

Deployment:

We can pick only one option either to enable or disable the publicNetworkAccess as this requirement cannot be achieved apart from these two ways.

Similarly we can do with disable the access by changing the prameters.
Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/#bicep
